# Referencing a CSS class only within a specific element

Tags: css, matching

I am trying to find the CSS syntax for a specific problem.
I really searched but couldn't find answer.
Here is the problem. My HTML markup is as follow:

```
<div>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   my content that I want red
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  my content that I want blue
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

I would like to display "my content that I want red" in red, and "my content that I want blue" in blue, and I only can use CSS for that.

Does anyone knows the trick that will make it? sub classes cant work here unfortunately.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: So you are saying you can't use .row{ color:red; } ?

Comment: Well yes it's possible to do it for this specific example, but in general it's not clear enough what do you want to do and what your entire markup is like.

Comment: Your markup seems a bit wrong too, you have a closing `</header>` tag but no opening one for it or is that just a typo? And why the tag 'matching'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lots of options.  It all really depends on your circumstances.  Here's a couple without modifying the HTML:

Using parent element

```
.row { color: blue }
header .row { color: red }
```

Using `:nth-of-type`

```
.column:nth-of-type(1) .row { color: red }
.column:nth-of-type(2) .row { color: blue }
```

If you're willing to add additional markup, you could always add additional classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this looks so simple that I am really confused asking :-(

Answer (score 3):

You probably didn't search very hard. [The W3C has defined over a dozen selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Here, you would use

```
header > div.container {
    color: red;
}

div > div.container {
    color:blue;
}
```

The angle bracket (`>`) is the first child selector. Since the second `container` isn't the first child of a `header` element, it will not have red text. Likewise, since the `container` with red text is the first child of a `header` and not a `div`, it, and only it, will have red text.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the 1st div for red, 2nd for blue, if the order stays the same.

You would probably need a parent container. Is the header tag supposed to parent both container divs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS nth-of-type

```
:nth-of-type
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/wn2BL/